# Silent audio in vlc, ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

When skipping trough videos in vlc by clicking on the timeline the audio sometimes goes silent. I can sometimes bring it back by clicking around on the timelime, or restarting the audio track. I'm having this problem both with alsa and pulse, what can I do?